# pull request to a GitHub project from a forked repo that DOES NOT exist on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'd like to know if I can send a pull request to a GitHub project from a forked repo that DOES NOT exist on GitHub ?  i.e - the project is forked from GitHub, but it does not exist on the GitHub server.

I've heard the pull-request system on GitHub has been modified from the original GIT version, so I was not sure if it is compatible from a non-GitHub repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible, especially considering [GitHub Pull Request 2.0](https://github.com/blog/712-pull-requests-2-0):

Not only a pull request is linked to a GitHub repo, it refers to issues, compare views and comments.

The simplest way remains to fork the GitHub repo, clone that fork, test your modifications from said clone, push back to your fork, and make the pull request from there.